# How to rotate an asterisk trapezoid in java?

Tags: java, loops, variable-assignment

In a school assignment we have to draw a trapezoid with asterisk in java. The constructor is like

`Trapezoid(int tWidth, int bWidth, char signA, char signB, int margin)`

tWidth: is the top width, bWidth: bottom width, signA: foreground sign, signB: background sign and margin: the margin (left and right) of the bWidth.

my `main()` class looks like this:

```
Trapezoid t = new Trapezoid(3, 9, '*', '-', 2);
t.printTrapezoid();
```

then it should look like this:

```
-----***-----
----*****----
---*******---
--*********--
```

the `printTrapezoid()` method looks like this:

```
int width = 2* margin + bWidth;
int length = (width - tWidth) / 2;

while (tWidth <= bWidth) {
    printChar(signB, length);
    printChar(signA, tWidth);
    printChar(signB, length);
    System.out.println();
    tWidth++;
}
```

The printChar() method looks like:

```
printChar(char signB, int length) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        System.out.print(signB);
    }
}
```

So. This works fine for me. But i think there are some other and better solutions for that. The next exercise is to rotate this trapezoid just with `t.rotate()` in the `main()` class. So that it looks like:

```
--*********--
---*******---
----*****----
-----***-----
```

I have no idea how to do it. Can anybody give me a hint?
Please, I don't want the solution here. Just a hint how i can solve it. Maybe it is better to refactor the draw method? I don't know...

Comment: If you are just flipping it, consider changing the top and bottom rows (width on top with width on bottom)

Comment: I'm confused about how this works, since `printTrapezoid` sets `length` only once, so it should be printing the same number of `-` on each line, the way you've written it.  Did you make a mistake in your post?

Comment: @HugoB. What happens when you switch `tWidth` and `bWidth`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown us the whole `Trapezoid` class, but I'm guessing that it has a field `tWidth` that you set in your constructor.

If that's the case, your `printTrapezoid` method shouldn't be changing it.  That field, the "top width", is a *property* of the trapezoid that shouldn't change when you print it out.  So in `printTrapezoid`, you should declare a local variable that's something like

```
int currentWidth = tWidth;
```

and then the method should modify this local variable, not the `tWidth` field.

Once you've done that, it should be very simple to see how to print the upside-down trapezoid, by making `currentWidth` become the same values in the reverse order.

**EDIT:** If `rotate` is supposed to change the properties of the trapezoid, rather than printing an upside-down trapezoid, then that should be easy too since you've fixed `printTrapezoid` not to change `tWidth` and `bWidth`, so now you can do what you need to do to change them (by swapping the values).